# restore current registered devices apple ios paid developer program

Tags: iphone, uuid, restore, provisioning-profile

I have just accidentally removed all the registered devices in my Apple ios program. This invalidated my provisioning profiles (which was expected as clearly stated) as well as that if now, I try to add the same devices with the same name the number of devices that I can register **decreases instead of staying the same.** In other words Apple's system "thinks" they are new devices even if the uuid is the same..

Anyone had a similar problem?

**How can I restore those devices** and how can I delete a device without loosing the number of devices available?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/contact/

Comment: Any help without having to contact them?.. is this the only way?

Comment: This is a customer support issue, not a programming question.  Ask Apple.

Comment: Yeah, Apple is going to have to help you with this. I had a similar issue happen to me just 3 months ago.

Comment: Ok, I had found similar questions on StackOverflow regarding creating provisioning profiles and thought that was similar... but ok, I see the reason for the dowvotes. Shall I remove the question?

Comment: @Jim I still believe that this is related to programming as without enough slots of uuids u cannot test ur app. Apple said that cannot do nothing to fix the mistake.. so there is no solution to this.

Comment: @Jim is there an area in StackOverflow where I can ask those questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developer.apple.com/support/ios/account-management.html

"You are allowed to register up to 100 iOS devices for testing and Ad Hoc distribution per membership year. Please Note: Although you may remove a device from your account, it will continue to count against your 100 device limit."

"At the start of your new membership year, Team Agents or Admins can sign in to the iOS Provsioning Portal to remove listed devices and restore the available device count to 100 devices. Be sure to remove all devices you no longer use for development prior to adding any new devices."

http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/business-legal-app-store/90078-device-ids-when-renewing-dev-account.html

"After I renew my membership, can I reset the devices I have assigned for testing and Ad Hoc distribution?

Yes. You are allowed to assign up to 100 devices for testing and Ad Hoc distribution per membership year. At that start of a new membership year, Team Agents and Team Admins can remove devices and restore the available device count for their development team to 100 devices. When Team Agents or Admins first log into the iOS Provisioning Portal at the start of a new membership year, they will be presented with the option to remove devices and restore the device count for those removed devices. Important Note : Devices can be removed and their device count restored only up until the first new device is added. Therefore, it is important to remove all devices you are no longer using for development prior to adding any new devices."

-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-

It looks like your only hope is to actually contact Apple about it and see if they would help you fix the mistake as MNRSullivan suggested.  I don't believe there's any other way to fix it quickly.  However, it looks like it will automatically refund you those registration slots at the beginning of a new year of your developer membership, so it will fix itself after a year of time...

Comment: Thank you. I accepted the answer although I don't understand why MNRSullivan removed his answer and added it as comment and did downvote without answering if I should remove or not the question. If I leave the question here I might get more downvotes and I haven't yet understood if this is dissimilar from other questions on provisioning profiles. I have sent an email to Apple..

Comment: I had actually been wondering this myself, but since I've only ever registered 15 devices, I never really looked into it until you asked about it.  But yea, let us know what Apple says.  I'm curious myself to see if they'd refund your devices after that small mistake.